# How to calculate week over week changes in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a data table that has 3 columns: Week, Type and units. I want to calculate the week over week changes in units for each Type, and the result table will be like this:

```
Week         Type   Units   Change
2020-12-01    A      10      null
2020-12-01    B      15      null
2020-12-01    C      20      null
2020-12-01    D      18      null
2020-12-08    A      20       10
2020-12-08    B      15       0
2020-12-08    C      25       5
2020-12-08    D      15      -3
...
```

I tried to use the lag function but failed maybe because I'm confused what to use in partition by and order by. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the previous "Units" for the same "Type", the partition is on the "Type".

```
SELECT *
, Units - LAG(Units) OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Week]) AS Change
FROM data_table
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer,  I tried your way but the result is not right. I want to calculate the changes.

Comment: Did you use the current version?